# Python cartopy projection fails with imshow set_data() method

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform, cartopy, map-projections

When plotting an image using `imshow`, I later want to change the data of that image `im` using the `im.set_data()` method. This, however, does not seem to work with the `cartopy Orthographic` projection (the input data use the `PlateCarree()` transform): After updating the data, the image apparently does not have the correct projection anymore.

Below is a minimal example using random data.

```
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(100)

fig = plt.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot(projection=ccrs.Orthographic())

im=ax.imshow(np.random.rand(20,20), transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.savefig('1.png')

im.set_data(np.random.rand(20,20))
plt.savefig('2.png')

im.set_transform(ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.savefig('3.png')
```

The image before updating data using `set_data()`. It looks as expected/desired:

[Image before updating data using `set_data()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmZiN.png)

The image after updating data using `set_data()`. Issue: The data look as if they were not projected to orthographic, but instead in still in the PlateCarree grid:

[Image after updating data using `set_data()`; issue: data appear to not be projected correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwqRY.png)

The image after updating data using `set_data()` and re-setting the image transform (unsure whether I understand `set_transform()` correctly). Issue: The data appear to have too small values:

[Image after updating data using `set_data()` and setting the transform via `set_transform`; issue: data appear to have very small values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxhzK.png)

Comment: How do you view all the images? Please show your code.

Comment: can you access the links?  usually i use the interactive mode (window just pops up) when i dont save the image